# Modify some text of a file in a zip file

Tags: linux, vim, zip

On linux, I would like to modify a file that is inside a zip without having to extract it. The file is in any possible extension.

Here's an exemple.

```
test.zip
 |---hello.someextension
 |---bye.someextension
```

The file **hello.someextension** contains following text: *Hello, this is a test.*

**What I would like to do**

Modify the word **test** in the **hello.someextension** file to be "gift" instead, for instance.
Modifying the text is not really a big deal, but the issue I'm facing is that I cannot edit a file that is inside a .zip. I tried via VIM and here's an exemple output:

```
ÅÍ.PE¥&ö$kpì`w_OËŽ=“XÖ¸m† 86=šoÔRw«Õºxÿ¯Ûiö²X
```

Comment: As Matt says, Vim *should* be able to edit a zip file -- see [`:help zip`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_zip.txt.html#zip). It could be your config disables it for some reason, it could be you're missing the "unzip" and "zip" commands on your system.

Answer (score 3):

Vim supports editing zipped files out-of-the-box. If it doesn't work for you then you have a local problem of some sort.

Check if it helps to bypass your faulty vimrc (e.g. `vim -u NORC -N`), or to re-install the whole Vim package etc.